# python | function repeating even after break

Tags: python, function

I have a function like this:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        ans=str(input("Do you wish to continue? :"))
        if ans == "yes":
            loop()
        elif ans =="no":
            break
```

After running this, I have noticed that if I answer "no", I'll have to re-enter "no" multiple times depending on how many times I've entered "yes". For example: If the first 2 times the function is run I enter "yes", then if I were to enter "no" afterwards, it would ask me whether I wish to continue again once, then twice then three times so that the number of times I'll have to enter "no" is the number of times I entered "yes" +1.

I need it so that even if I enter "yes" an odd 20 times, if I were to enter "no" the next time, I should not again be asked whether "I wish to continue" several times. This means just entering "no" once should stop the entire program.

Comment: It's because you call `loop()`. Why do you do that? Show us more code and what you're trying to accomplish so we can suggest what to do instead. My guess is that you don't need to take any action at all, just say `if ans =="no": break` and don't check for `yes`.

Comment: I need it so that if the user enter anything other than yes or no, they will be asked again whether they want to continue

Answer (score 4):

You are not resuming your loop, you are calling your function again from within the function itself. This is called *recursion* and `break` won't break out of it. `break` will break out of the current loop, but that just returns to the previous incarnation of the function, which is still looping, and you have to answer `no` in *that* one too, and so on until you have answered `no` as many times as you have answered `yes`. Then the next time you enter `no`, it stops the program.

Instead of using `loop()` to start over from the beginning of the loop, use `continue` (to restart the loop from the top) or `pass` (to continue whatever else is in the loop). Or remove the test for `yes` entirely; the loop keeps going until you exit it, so there is no need to explicitly tell Python to keep going.

Comment: `continue` will ask the question again instead of moving on to the rest of the loop body. Perhaps you mean `pass`.

Comment: But there's nothing else in the loop body, and the loop is `while True` so it's going to continue regardless.

Comment: my bad, I meant to put the while loop inside loop(), I have now fixed it

Comment: I'm assuming OP has simply left out the rest of the loop body or the program would be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

That's because if You type in `YES` another instance of the function is being called, but the previous one is not ended yet, so You have to type `NO` for every instance of the started `loop()` function.

```
         LOOP() 
     YES        NO
    LOOP()     BREAK
 YES     NO
LOOP()   BREAK
 ...
```

There is no need to call new function every type in the "yes branch":

```
def loop():
while True:
    ans=str(input("Do you wish to continue? :"))
    if ans == "yes":
        pass
    elif ans =="no":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that answering anything but "no" will cause the loop to continue.

```
def loop():
    while True: # the while is the actual loop
        ans=str(input("Do you wish to continue? :"))
        if ans == "no":
            break

def recur_loop():
    ans=str(input("Do you wish to continue? :"))
    if ans == "no":
        return
    recur_loop()
```